# iTerm2 error notification ‘Couldn't log to 2020…’

Tags: macos, high-sierra, error, iterm

Every time I open a new window iTerm2 says "Couldn't log to …"

[image: Couldn't log to]

I restarted my Mac which is on High Sierra but the problem continues.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an invalid or inaccessible log path.

From iTerm Preferences → Profiles → *your profile* → Session, disable ‘Automatically log session input to files in’ or set the path correctly using the Change button.

> [image]

https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/8672#note_284043217